# foreach produces just one result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three email text boxes with three different values in it. But it produces the same result. I have this:

```
$('.contactpersonen-email').each(function() {
    var mails = $('.contactpersonen-email').map(function(){                 
        return $(this).val();   
    }).get(); 
    console.log(mails); 
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="contact-label span2">
    <label for="contactpersonen-email">Email adres</label>
    <div class="contact-input-field">
        <input type="text" class="input-text span2  contactpersonen-email" id="contactpersonen-email0" name="contactpersonen-email"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the whole script:

```
<![CDATA[
                            $(document).ready(function()
                            {
                                // Form validation
                                $(".klantregistratie form").validate({
                                    rules: {
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Bedrijfsnaam: "required",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Postcode: "required",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Plaats: "required",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Emailadres: {
                                            required: true,
                                            email: true
                                        },
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_KvK_nummer: "required",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_naam_eigenaar: "required",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Telefoon_mobiel: "required"
                                    },
                                    messages: {
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Bedrijfsnaam: "De bedrijfsnaam is niet ingevuld",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Postcode: "De postcode is niet ingevuld",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Plaats: "De plaats is niet ingevuld",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Emailadres: {
                                            required: "Je hebt geen email adres ingevuld",
                                            email: "Je hebt geen geldig email adres ingevuld"
                                        },
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_KvK_nummer: "Het KVK nummer is niet ingevuld",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_naam_eigenaar: "De naam van de eigenaar is niet ingevuld",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Telefoon_mobiel: "Het (mobiele) telefoon nummer is niet ingevuld"
                                    }
                                });




                                // Hide the textarea
                                $('#verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Contactpersonen').parent().parent().hide();

                                // Add extra contact clicked?
                                $('#add-contact p a').click(function()
                                {
                                    // Make a copy of the first input fields
                                    html = $('#new-contact').children().clone();

                        // Get number of tabs in the accordion
                        var index = $('#accordion h3').length;

                                    // Remove the values
                                    html.find("input[type=text]").val("");
                  html.find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);

                        // New 'id', 'for' and 'name' attribute names
                        html.find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                            me = $(this);
                            attr = me.attr('id');
                            number = attr.split('_')[2];
                            newNumber = parseInt(index) + 1;
                            newAttr = attr.replace(number, newNumber);
                            me.attr('id', newAttr).attr('name', newAttr).next().attr('for', newAttr);
                        });                  

                                    // Insert it at the end
                        $('#accordion').append(html);
                        $('#accordion').accordion('refresh');

                        // Set last tab to active
                        $("#accordion").accordion({ active: index });

                                    // Cancel the click
                                    return false;
                                });

                                // Submit clicked?
                                $('.submit-button input').click(function()
                                {
                                    // Set variables
                                    var html = '';
                                    var i = 1;

                        // Loop through all the input fields for contacts
                        $('#accordion .user-row').each(function (uindex, uvalue) {


var mails = [];
$('.contactpersonen-email').each(function() {
    mails.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(mails);




        Array.prototype.areUnique = function() {
    var l = this.length;
    for(var i=0; i<l; i++) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<l; j++) {
            if (this[i] === this[j]) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};

//if (!mails.areUnique()) {
  // console.log ('values are not unique');
//} else {
 //   console.log('values are unique');
//}         


                            html += '<tr>';

                            $(this).find('input').each(function (index, value) {



                                // Check if input type is a checkbox
                                if ($(this).is(":checkbox")) {
                                    var JaNee = 'Nee';
                                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) JaNee = 'Ja';
                                    html = html + '<td>' + JaNee + '</td>';
                                }
                                else {
                                    // Add the value into the html
                                    html = html + '<td>' + $(this).val() + '</td>';
                                }
                            });

                            html += '</tr>';
                        });

                                    // Set the value from the textarea to the generated html
                                    $('#verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Contactpersonen').val('<table>'+html+'</table>');
                                });
                            });

              $(function () {
                    $("#accordion").accordion({
                        heightStyle: "content"
                    });
                });
                        ]]>
```

SO thank you. Als with validation. and accordian. The html is the same. So there is one text box for email

I have it now like this:

```
 // Loop through all the input fields for contacts
                        $('#accordion .user-row').each(function (uindex, uvalue) {


var mails = $('.contactpersonen-email').map(function(){                 
        return $(this).val();   
    }).get(); 
    console.log(mails);
```

Comment: Per your html, you only have **1**  email box.

Comment: Why you need the `.get();` in the last sentence after `map()`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Beause it is a accordian. So every time you add a contact there is a email adress text box. But so I try to generate unique class name

Comment: Well then you need to attach to the accordian data elements that get created, and not the input box.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude because `$(selector).map()` returns jQuery object and to get array from that you use `get()`

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try the following:

```
var mails = [];
$('.contactpersonen-email').each(function() {
    mails.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(mails);
```

Comment: Thank you. But still I only get two times the same value from the first email text box: hh. Because in the second email text box I have: jj. but it show this:["hh"]
klant-worden:656 ["hh"]

Comment: Yes, please post more code so we can help you. From your question, I assumed you have several `input` fields with the class `contactpersonen-email`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the outer `each` . The `map()` is already going to loop over all the elements so you are actually creating the same array numerous times

Just use:

```js
    var mails = $('.contactpersonen-email').map(function(){                 
        return $(this).val();   
    }).get(); 
    console.log(mails);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input-text span2  contactpersonen-email" value="email 1">
<input type="text" class="input-text span2  contactpersonen-email" value="email 2">
<input type="text" class="input-text span2  contactpersonen-email" value="email 3">
```

Comment: Yes,  I had that. But that produces two times the same result

Comment: No it doesn't. Look in console when you run the snippet. You were getting it twice because of doing it inside `each`

Comment: I have it under:  // Loop through all the input fields for contacts
               $('#accordion .user-row').each(function (uindex, uvalue) {

Comment: But still it shows just one value. What I do wrong then? I also do it outside the each Thank you

Comment: perhaps classes are different. Hard to help without seeing proper html used